# Boy in a gold space suit / Kids book in UK pre 1971

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I'm trying to find a sf novel for kids published in the UK before 1971. Here's what I remember from reading it in 1971:

1. It was hardback
2. It was illustrated
3. It had a plot about a boy in a gold space suit landing in the UK
4. He met some kids at a school
5. A teacher told the kids she believed in UFOs
6. It had a scene with a canal boat.